# Add a kernel parameter ? `mmcblk.perdev_minors`

Tags: kernel, xubuntu

In order to see and be able to mount more than 8 partitions in a flash drive (mmcblk), I need to change the kernel parameter `mmcblk.perdev_minors`.

How can I do it ?

- With a livecd Xubuntu/Ubuntu. (Is it possible to change the parameter after the boot ?)

The flash drive is a tablet's rom with dual OS with android, I cannot launch another drive, I need to change this kernel parameter in the livecd.

Answer (score 1):

You can add kernel parameters in the Grub boot menu (which I assume is provided when you boot from CD). The following is from the top of my head and may not be totally accurate, so read the hints on the screen, too:

1. When the Grub boot menu appears press the letter <kbd>e</kbd> to change the selected boot option.
2. Select the long line with the kernel parameters (the second IIRC) and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit.
3. Press <kbd>End</kbd> to set the cursor to the end of the line.
4. Enter the additional option(s).
5. Press 'Enter' to finish editing, <kbd>b</kbd> to boot with the current options.